# Sufficient condition for directed graph having an even directed cycle.

Tags: graph-theory

I want to show that a directed graph $D$ on $n$ vertices with minimum out-degree $(\log_2 n) + 1$ always has an even directed cycle.

I first saw this claim [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669885800251) with a version as an exercise [here](http://math.mit.edu/~fox/MAT307-hw2-2009.pdf). I'm trying to use the hint in the exercises to see a proof different from the one presented in the paper.

So far, I've been trying to use the probabilistic method to show that $D$ must have a bipartite directed subgraph where every vertex has out degree at least $1$. From this result, though, I'm not sure how to guarantee an even directed cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the two sets of vertices in the directed bipartite subgraph be $U$ and $V$. Let
$$
P = x_0 \rightarrow x_1 \rightarrow x_2 \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow x_m
$$
be the **longest** path such that

- $x_{i+1}$ is an out-neighbor of $x_i$;
- $x_{i+1} \notin \{x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_i\}$.

Therefore, all $x_m$'s out-neighbors are in $\{x_0, x_1, \cdots, x_{m-1}\}$; otherwise, $P$ is not the longest. Let $x_k$ for some $0 \leq k \leq m - 1$ be an out-neighbor of $x_m$. Then
$$
x_k \rightarrow x_{k+1} \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow x_m \rightarrow x_k
$$
is an even directed cycle because the vertices alternate between $U$ and $V$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use probabilistic methods to do this problem. Hint: Assign a color to each vertex uniformly at random. Then calculate the probability that an edge lie between two colors.

Comment: This question is quite old, and the person who asked it is long gone, it seems. I think you may if you wish go beyond your brief hint, if you feel you've a solution distinct from the existing answer. Welcome to Math Stack.